# Сделайте синтаксический разбор сложных предложений. Составьте схемы их строения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

И если прогресс наравне с умножением средств благосостояния состоит в одновременном повышении моральных обязанностей, потому что только совершенный человек способен добиться совершенного счастья, для этого надлежало каждому иметь и совершенную биографию, чтоб не стыдно было рассказать ее вслух, при детях, в солнечный полдень, на самых людных площадях мира (Леон.).

Вот мои попытки

Повествовательное, не восклицательное, сложное, связь союзная, средство связи подчинительные союзы потому что, если, чтоб, для этого, СПП.

1-е ПП: двусоставное, грамматическая основа – прогресс состоит, распространенное, не осложнено.

2-е ПП: двусоставное, грамматическая основа – мы с классом поехали, распространенное, не осложнено.

3-е ПП: осложнено однородными членами предложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) И если прогресс наравне с умножением средств благосостояния состоит в одновременном повышении моральных обязанностей, (2) потому что только совершенный человек способен добиться совершенного счастья, (3) (то) для этого надлежало каждому иметь и совершенную биографию, (4)чтоб не стыдно было рассказать ее вслух, при детях, в солнечный полдень, на самых людных площадях мира (Леон.).

**Это одно сложное предложение (сложное синтаксическое целое)**, состоит из 4-х предложений. Между (1) и (3) подчинительная связь , предложение (1) – придаточное условия.

Придаточное условия  (1) является главным по отношению к придаточному причины (2), а предложение (3) имеет придаточное цели (4).

Предложения (1) и (4) – это неоднородные придаточные, отнесенные к одному главному (3), такая связь является **параллельной**. А связь предложений 3, 1, 2 – **это последовательное подчинение**.

Всё это надо изобразить в виде схемы, где указаны предикативные основы и союзы.

**Предикативные основы**: прогресс состоит, человек способен добиться, надлежало иметь, не стыдно было рассказать.

Примечание. В предложении 3 хорошо бы использовать сослагательное наклонение "надлежало бы".